# Strategy to improve Oracle DELETE performance

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We've got an Oracle 11g installation that is starting to get big. This database is the backend to a parallel optimization system running on a cluster. Input to the process is contained in the database along with output from the optimization steps. The input includes rote configuration data and some binary files (using 11g's SecureFiles). The output includes 1D, 2D, 3D, and 4D data currently stored in the DB.

DB Structure:

```
/* Metadata tables */
Case(CaseId, DeleteFlag, ...) On Delete Cascade CaseId
OptimizationRun(OptId, CaseId, ...) On Delete Cascade OptId
OptimizationStep(StepId, OptId, ...) On Delete Cascade StepId

/* Data tables */
Files(FileId, CaseId, Blob) /* deletes are near instantateous here */

/* Data per run */
OnedDataX(OptId, ...)
TwoDDataY1(OptId, ...) /* packed representation of a 1D slice */

/* Data not only per run, but per step */
TwoDDataY2(StepId, ...)  /* packed representation of a 1D slice */
ThreeDDataZ(StepId, ...) /* packed representation of a 2D slice */
FourDDataZ(StepId, ...)  /* packed representation of a 3D slice */
/* ... About 10 or so of these tables exist */
```

A reaper script comes around daily and looks for cases with the `DeleteFlag = 1` and proceeds with the `DELETE FROM Case WHERE DeleteFlag = 1`, allowing the cascades to continue.

This strategy works great for read/write, but is now outstripping our capabilities when we want to purge data! The rub is deleting a Case takes ~20-40 minutes depending on the size and often overloads our archiver space. The next major version of the product will take a "from the ground up" approach to solving the problem. The next minor release needs to stay within the confines of data stored in the database.

So, for the minor release we need an approach that can improve delete performance and at most require moderate changes to the database.

1. REF Partitioning, but the question is HOW? I would love to do INTERVAL on `Case` and REF on the rest, [but that isn't supported](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/PartitioningEnhancements_11gR1.php#reference_partitioning). Is there some way to manually partition `OptimizationRun` by `CaseId` through a trigger?
2. Disable archiving/redo logs for deletes? Couldn't find a HINT to go with this one. Not sure it is even feasible.
3. <strike>Truncate? This likely would need some sorta complicated table setup. But maybe I'm not considering all of my option.</strike> *(per answer, stricken)*

To help illustrate the issue, the data in question per case ranges from 15MiB to 1.5GiB with anywhere from 20k to 2M rows.

**Update:** Current size of the DB is ~1.5TB.

Comment: A design question:  If the dependency tree is `Case -> OptimizationRun -> OptimizationStep` as it appears, why do some tables carry both?  If using `DELETE CASCADE`, you're running the delete against those 12/13 tables twice; once for the OptID key, and again for the StepID key!  If one of those foreign keys isn't indexed, the performance would be even worse!

Comment: @Adam Musch: that is a mistake, there is only 1 key on those tables. Thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleting data is a hell of a job, for the database. It has to create before images, update indexes, write redo logs and remove the data. This is a slow process. If you can have a window to perform this task, easiest and fastest is to build new tables, containing the wanted data. Drop the old tables and rename the new tables.
This requires some setup work, that is obvious but is very well possible to make.
One step less drastic is to drop the indexes before the delete takes place. My vote would go for CTAS (Create Table As Select from) and build the new tables.
A nice partitioning schema would certainly be helpful, maybe in the next release Oracle can combine interval and reference partitioning. It would be very nice to have.

Disabling logging .... can not be done for deletes but CTAS can use nologging. Make a backup when ready and make sure to transfer the datafiles to the standby database, if you have one.

Comment: I guess my issue with the CTAS approach is we'd be "copying" 49-99GB of the 50-100GB any time we deleted just 1 case. Also I don't think this would work well if we were nearly full on tablespace to begin with.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Depending on how the storage is configured, it can be done in half an hour. If the data is not frequently modified, you could think about compression of the tables during the CTAS. In that case you could very well win space. An other option is to schedule delete jobs that are continuously removing data. Smartest is not to use the cascade but start deleting from the child tables up to the parent tables. Are the foreign keys indexed?

Comment: Yes the FK's are indexed. We didn't see any improvement in a manual delete however.

Comment: Are triggers playing a role in the response time? They can really kill performance. What plan are the deletes using? In manual bulk deletes starting with the children I expect a better performance than falling back to the cascade option. Are lots of indexes in place? Could you drop them?

Comment: There are triggers, but I don't believe they execute on delete. By "bulk delete" are you referring to just `DELETE FROM table WHERE id = ...`?

Comment: more like ..... where id in (..) If your code is looping and deleting rows one at a time it might take a while. Prefer to work with sets. first all grand children, next the children, as last the parents.

Comment: Let me see about updating the stored proc to try that approach. I could probably get the bigger child tables via bulk deletes, and let the smaller child tables cascade.

Comment: Bulk deletes are no faster than on delete cascade. Likely the overhead with on delete cascade is less than the cost somewhere else.

Comment: What do the awr reports tell?

Comment: ON DELETE CASCADE took ~35 minutes for a case w/ 1.3GB of data in the DB, a similar sized case using a more manual method took ~27 minutes. My original test for bulk deletes only had 1 commit at the end, the new version commits after each delete and shaved about 7-8 minutes. Interesting.

Comment: You should be able to win a little time by committing less frequently. As I said before, deleting data is a nightmare for the db. Still, your times look worse than I expected. The awr report should give a clue.

Answer (score 2):

Just some thoughts:

1. I assume you have indexes on all foreign keys.  ON DELETE CASCADE will hold row level locks until the Case delete is complete, and with no indexes will hold table locks I believe and be super slow of course
2. Do you have any deferred constraints?  This would most likely slow things down for Oracle cascading through the various table deletes
3. Have you tried to do the deletes separately for all affected tables (instead of relying on on delete cascade)?  Not as easy, but you may be surprised.

EDIT:

One more thought.  You may consider doing a SOFT delete on Case table, meaning you have a status field that will tell your app if that Case should be considered.  This flag could have many different values, but maybe 'A' for active and 'I' for inactive.  Assuming you are always using Case as a driving/primary table in joins to other tables, you can avoid the HARD deletes all-together (and occasionally do a cleanup off hours on whatever schedule if you like).  Apps would need to be aware of this flag of course, and you'd be tied to joining back to Case table.  May or may not fit for your situation...

Comment: We have to do the hard delete to free up space. It already uses the DeleteFlag as a soft delete. Separate deletes don't appear to speed anything up. No deferred constraints.

Comment: Disk is cheap nowadays.  I would say your cascading deletes are more expensive.  Besides, deletes don't reset the High water mark, so your future inserts will be above that HWM, and won't really save space like you may think.  You would need to do a truncate or CTAS to really free up space.

Comment: Theoretically disk is cheap; in reality it can take 1-2 months to get storage added to our database. Would switching to a partitioning strategy allow us to manage the space better?

Comment: well, truncating a partition would free up space, whereas deleting millions of rows won't.  Again, not sure of your pain point exactly.  If its truly space, then doing deletes won't help, and on top of that you are creating a bigger problem by generating all those logs.  But maybe I'm misunderstanding you here

Comment: No you're following me, just I guess I wasn't aware of the implication of delete. We lost our proactive DBA and the lowly software engineers (read: me) have been left to making broad database decisions! Likely, in order to minimize database architecture changes in this version, I need to explore partitioning and truncation on that side. Maybe an interim CTAS to remove current stale data prior to the partitioning strategy.

Comment: Ok, np, just thought I wasn't getting something ;)  You need a reorg or rebuild of some sort (several approaches, CTAS, truncate partition, alter table move, alter table shrink space).  Basically when you delete, the blocks are still there, it just doesn't contain the row info.  So if you had 100 million rows and deleted all but ONE, then ran a count query, Oracle would still need to scan all those blocks to see whats in there (they didn't disappear on delete), which is why a truncate or CTAS is preferred for this.

Comment: My guess is this means in *Version Now* I should explore partitions that I can drop, probably thru triggers. In *Version Now+1* I need to store this data differently.

Comment: If a lot of deletes are typical for this system, definitely design for it (a partitioning strategy would make a lot of sense)

Comment: When deleting a row thus freeing up space inside a block, Oracle may reuse that free space for a subsequent insert. Depending on the update patterns you may not need to reclaim any space at all, since you may be inserting/deleting for the same amount of storage anyway. Also, for indexed access, the high watermark doesn't matter.

Comment: @tbone and @Ronnis: how would I determine which strategy oracle is using for the new free space?

Comment: The big assumption is that your deletes will be enough out of a block to fall below pctused and go onto freelist to be used for subsequent inserts.  In my many years using Oracle, large amount of deletes is simply not a good approach for purpose of reclaiming space (+ its slow and generates a ton of logs).  Your best bet imo, if partitioning isnt an option for your situation, is to flag the records as you do, and on some schedule (once/week off hours maybe) rebuild the tables via CTAS approach (excluding the recs flagged for delete of course).

Comment: The schedule would likely have to be quarterly. I'm going to put another question together on the best partitioning strategy as that would probably be the biggest bang for the least about of restructuring.

Answer (score 1):

`CASCADE DELETE` runs internally slow-by-slow, er, row-by-row.

Some options:

1. Have your purge job snapshot all the cases to be purged into a scratch table with a CTAS.  Then have your purge job loop over that table, deleting each case (and its children) individually.  This can be unpleasant, especially if you run into millions of descendant rows.  We had to change one of the processes recently at [business redacted] which did that to determine which ultimate parents had child counts that would be problematic, and then use a `rownum` limiter on a delete against the problematic child table(s).  It's not fast, but at least it's safer from an undo/redo management perspective by placing an upper bound on how big any transaction can be.
2. If you're using `CASCADE DELETE` as a convenience, you could always not do so.  You'd have to write a more sophisticated purge routine that deletes from your dependency tree "bottom up".
3. If you can afford the undo/redo generation on the soft delete, you could range-partition the ultimate parent on `DeleteFlag`, then partition the children `BY REFERENCE`, all tables using ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT.  You'd incur undo/redo costs for moving the rows when soft-deleted, but when it came time to finally purge, it would be truncating partitions where `DeleteFlag = 1`, nothing more.
4. Adding storage is relatively cheap.  If there's a date-based retention option, use it, and just have the soft delete option hide the data from the application front end.  It's inelegant, but then, so is `CASCADE DELETE`.

Comment: 1. We're sorta doing that right now in production, limiting by rownum. 2. Bottoms up is no faster and no slower. I don't know why. 3. How big of a performance penalty is enable row movement? 4. "Cheap" by what definition. If I want to add space it'll take 1-2 months regardless of price, just the reality of the business.

Comment: The performance cost for using row movement would be on the order of actually inserting and deleting that much data.  The potential advantage would be that the delete cost would be "baked in" to the operations of the system.  With deletes vs. drops or truncates, it's always going to be pay now or pay later.

Answer (score 1):

Not advised for live database.

1. I disabled the foreign key constraints referencing the table which is slow to delete.
2. I executed the delete
3. Enabled the foreign keys again.

Comment: In a production database this is not safe to do, it may work for small projects or personal projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use Enterprise Manager to create a AWR report and run it through [statspack analyzer](http://www.statspackanalyzer.com/analyze090630.asp) which will give you detailed instructions about the bottlenecks in your system. A AWR report is a textfile containing all kinds of data about what the database has done during a certain time and how long it took.... That statspack analyzer ist sort of an automatic DBA telling you what to do.

Forget partitions until Statspack Analyzer tells you that they could be useful and you've got a few idle disks that you can use to distribute the I/O.

Don't think about truncate. It forces a commit...

BTW, I'm not affiliated with Statspack Analyzer, but I think it's a very viable general tuning approach for Oracle, especially if there's no DBA around.

Comment: 1. Straight from the oracle docs: INTERVAL partitioning cannot be used with REF partitioning. I wasn't referring to all partitioning, just that combination. 2. Nologging does not affect delete's, and I don't want to lose logging for writes. 3. Sounds good.

Comment: for that size of DB I'd definitely do a statspack report first.

Comment: We've been analyzing it with precise i3 and learned that our delete's were the bottleneck.

Comment: I believe that a statspack report would go beyond i3. In order to tune your deletes you'd have to find out 1st how much physical I/O they cause and how the I/O is distributed accross your partitions.

Comment: 0 partitions, so pretty easy to find distribution :)